# How to access two polymorphic associations with one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 6 app I have these models:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :carriers
  has_many :clients

  # Unfortunately, these two don't work together. I have to uncomment one of them to get the other one to work:
  has_many :people, :through => :carriers # works but omits clients
  has_many :people, :through => :clients # works but omits carriers

end
```

---

```
class Carrier < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :account

  has_many :people, :as => :personalizable

end
```

---

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  
  belongs_to :account

  has_many :people, :as => :personalizable

end
```

---

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :personalizable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

---

How can I access an account's `carriers` **and** `clients` in one query?

I would love to do something like `account.people` to show **all** the account's people but haven't found a way to achieve that yet.

How can it be done?

Comment: Does `has_many :people, -> { joins(:carriers, :clients) }"'` work for you?

Comment: No, @benjessop, unfortunately it doesn't. I am getting this error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Person' to association named 'carriers'; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use same method name for two associations instead you can rename it as `carrier_people` and `client_people` and eager load both.

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :carriers
  has_many :clients

  has_many :carrier_people, :through => :carriers, source: :people # works but omits clients
  has_many :client_people, :through => :clients, source: :people # works but omits carriers

end
```

You can eager load like this.

```
Account.includes(:carrier_people, :client_people)
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I filter the association? I tried something like `Account.includes(:carrier_people, :client_people).people.where(:first_name => "John")` but it gives me an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'people' for #<Account::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fe4e46f71d0>)`

Comment: You can do this, Account.includes(:carrier_people, :client_people).where(carrier_people: {first_name: "John"}).or(Account.includes(:carrier_people, :client_people).where(client_people: {first_name: "John"}))

Comment: Wow, it's more complicated than I thought!